# Intermediate code generator for Java

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, intermediate-code

is there a tool for generating intermediate code for java files?Or are there any resources that could help in generating one?Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Java source is normally compiled to an intermediate representation known as Java bytecode. If that's what you want, then you just need a Java compiler. If you want the JVM assembler code, the you can run the disassembler, javap, over the .class file.

If it isn't either of those, then you'll have to be more specific about which intermediate code you want.